# Can't find Surveys page, yet Surveys is enabled?

Tags: lightning-apps, setup, survey

I want to be able to go to the survey page, and use the salesforce survey builder.

**Here's what my screen looks like:**

[image]

Comment: 1. Check Tab settings it might be default to Tab Hidden 2. You can copy and paste it after .com in browser url `lightning/o/Survey/home` which will navigate to survey tab. 3. Wait for sometime and survey tab should be visible.

Comment: The link worked for me, but I want the survey tab to populate. I been waiting and it still hasn't populate.

Comment: Can you check if tab is hidden on profile?

Comment: What are the sets to check if a tab is hidden?

Comment: You can check Tab Settings along with object perm.

Comment: Found it, I had to go under "User Profiles" and select an profile to edit, then under "Tab Settings" via "Surveys" switched it to "Default On".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The "Surveys Page" was hidden from me, here's how I got it to be shown:**

*User Profiles -> Edit select profile -> Tab Settings -> Surveys -> Switch to: "Default On".*